# CSS / jQuery - Cycle through random characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple HTML snippet like this:

```
<div class="numbers">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>5</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the numbers cycle randomly 1-9 live on the screen, so each span will fade between 1-9.

I am planning on using Javascript / jQuery to try and achieve this, but before I start I wanted to see if this is something that is possible using just CSS instead?

Does anybody have an example of something similar being done?

Comment: What do you mean by cycle randomly and fade?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible generate random number only with CSS. You can use jQuery for it. `setInterval`, `random()` and `loop` is your friend.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $('.numbers').find('span').each(function(index, element) {
    let rNum = '',
      num = "123456789";
    rNum = num.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * num.length));
    $(this).text(rNum);
  });
}, 1500)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="numbers">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```